# Get pointer to C Structure in Swift

Tags: c, swift

I am converting a C signal processing library for use in Swift.

So I am trying to write a test but the call to `vsip_vgetattrib_d` fails because I am not getting a pointer to `attr`.

```
func testAttr(){
    let v = Vector(length: 10, type: "d")
    var attr: vsip_vattr_d
    var attrPtr: UnsafeMutablePointer<vsip_vattr_d> = &attr
    vsip_vgetattrib_d(v.vsip!,attrPtr)
    print(attr)
}
```

In C this would look like

```
vsip_vattr_d attr
vsip_vgetattrib_d(v,&attr)
```

and `attr` would be filled with the proper values.

note I have a workaround.

The following works fine

```
func testAttr(){
    let v = Vector(length: 10, type: "d")
    let attr: vsip_vattr_d = vsip_vattr_d(offset: v.offset, stride: v.stride, length: v.length, block: v.sBlock.vsip)
    //vsip_vgetattrib_d(v.vsip!,attrPtr)
    print(attr)
}
```

and prints:

> vsip_vattr_d(offset: 0, stride: 1, length: 10, block: 0x000060000026f740)

But this problem will bite me again and again so I need to figure out how to make a pointer to a C structure to pass into my functions as inout arguments when needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass an (initialised) *variable* of type `T` as 
`inout` expression (with `&`) to functions expecting an `UnsafeMutablePointer<T>`, so this should work:

```
func testAttr(){
    let v = Vector(length: 10, type: "d")
    var attr = vsip_vattr_d()
    vsip_vgetattrib_d(v.vsip!, &attr)
    print(attr)
}
```